# Firefox add-on error with jquery 1.9.1

Tags: jquery, firefox, firefox-addon

Using Firefox 18 with the Jetpack SDK. Upon injecting jquery-1.9.1.js into my page, I get the following error in the console:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "resource://jid1-t5mdaatmx3urka-at-jetpack/yesware/data/jquery.min.js", line 9597, in 
    })( window );
  File "resource://jid1-t5mdaatmx3urka-at-jetpack/yesware/data/jquery.min.js", line 1307, in 
    jQuery.support = (function() {
  File "resource://jid1-t5mdaatmx3urka-at-jetpack/yesware/data/jquery.min.js", line 1446, in jQuery.support<
    support[ i + "Bubbles" ] = eventName in window || div.attributes[ eventName ].expando === false;
TypeError: div.attributes[eventName] is undefined
```

I looked it up in the development version of jQuery and line 1446 refers to this block:

```
     // Support: IE<9 (lack submit/change bubble), Firefox 17+ (lack focusin event)
    // Beware of CSP restrictions (https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Security/CSP), test/csp.php
    for ( i in { submit: true, change: true, focusin: true }) {
        div.setAttribute( eventName = "on" + i, "t" );

        support[ i + "Bubbles" ] = eventName in window || div.attributes[ eventName ].expando === false;
    }
```

It says to beware of CSP restrictions but the Firefox dev site isn't telling me much. What should I do?

Btw, everything works fine if I just take this block out of jquery. Of course, I don't like to be messing with things I don't fully understand.

Comment: Looks like upgrading to the latest Firefox SDK worked!

Comment: related: Upgrade Jquery to fix CSP issues caused by inline event handlers. https://github.com/mozilla/addons-server/issues/1312

Fixed by upgrading jQuery from 1.9.1 to 1.12.0